# サービスコンテナにサービスが反映されない

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

自己解決したのでいったん削除しましたが、誰かの役に立つかもしれないので再掲します。

`Laravel 5.1`の環境で、ライブラリの開発を行おうとしています。
まず、作成直後のプロジェクトに、`extlib/vendor/codename`というフォルダーを作り、そこを開発するライブラリの置き場所にすることにしました。このパスを認識させるために、`composer.json`に以下のパスを追加し、`composer dumpautoload`を行いました。

```
(前略)
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "codename\\": "extlib/vendor/codename"  註：この行を追加
    }
},
(後略)
```

この配下に`service`. `provider`, `facade`といったフォルダーを作成し、サービス用のクラスや、サービスプロバイダークラス、ファサードクラスを作成して置いてあります。

この設定の中で、`Foo`サービスを`FooProvider`で`singleton`登録し、さらに`FooFacade`を通して使おうとしています。

```
<?php // Fooサービス
namespace codename\service;

class Foo
{
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return 'ごきげんよう';
    }
}

<?php // FooProviderサービスプロバイダー
namespace codename\provider;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use codename\service\Foo;

class FooProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('ex-foo', function ($app) {
            return new Foo();
        });
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        \Log::info(app()->getBindings()); // ex-fooは一覧にある。
        \Log::info(app('ex-foo')->getMessage());  // これは出力される
    }
}
```

`boot`メソッドに記述したログ出力は期待通りに出力されているため、サービスコンテナへの登録はうまくいっているものと考えました。

しかし、確認のために`routes.php`に以下のようなルーティングを追加して、内容表示を試みたところ、`Class ex-foo does not exist`となってしまいます。同様に、バインド一覧を確認しましたが、やはり一覧には登録がありませんでした。

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    \Log::info(app()->getBindings()); // 一覧にはex-fooはない。

    // $s = new codename\service\Foo(); // こちらはOK
    // $s = app()->make('ex-foo'); // Class ex-foo does not exist
    $s = app('ex-foo'); // Class ex-foo does not exist

    return $s->getMessage();
});
```

ちなみに、`Facade`経由の場合も`Class ex-foo does not exist`となります。主因はそれ以前にあるので、こちらは省略します。あたかも、違うサービスコンテナを見ているような状況なのですが、Laravelの経験が浅いためその理由がつかめません。解決方法やヒントをお持ちでしたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: タイトルで解決済みの表記は止め、回答を承認することで解決済みとしましょう。自己回答については数日後に承認出来るようになります。(詳しい日数は忘れたけど2日くらいだったはず……)

Comment: 承知しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan clear-compiled`を行うことで、正常に動作するようになりました。

しかし、ログには`FooProvider`からは正常な結果が出て、`router`からは見えないという現象なのはなぜなのか、よくわかりませんでした。それぞれの見ているサービスコンテナのインスタンスが違うとしか思えませんでした。

こんな情報でも、どなたかのお役に立てばよいですが、、。